# editing/updating password in rails admin, using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm having trouble creating a new user, or editing an existing user via rails admin. The user model uses devise, and the password fields are visible but read-only.  I overrode this in the initializer, which makes the fields editable, but the validation indicates that 'password' cannot be blank.  seems like it should be attr_accessible but I have that set.  Seems to be some trick w/ Devise and rails admin, but not sure what.  Rails 3.2.11

Here is my User Model setup:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
attr_accessible :email, :password, password_confirmation
```

in my rails_admin.rb (initializer)

```
config.model User do

edit do
    field :email
    field :password
    field :password_confirmation
end
end
```

I've also tried 
    edit do
        field :password do
            read_only false
        end
    do
which makes the fields editable, but cannot save because it thinks password is blank.

Comment: Thanks for asking that question and thereby showing me that awesome rails admin gem! +1 from me